# xpath filter on attribute text

Tags: vb.net, xpath

Hi I have an xml file like below,

```
<Pods>
 <item>
    <URL>data/_data/2014/09/11/pods/10057-1837887-2965978-0.pdf</URL>
    <RunDate>11/09/2014</RunDate>
    <DateSigned>11/09/2014 09:13:49
    </DateSigned>
 </item>
 <item>
    <URL>data/_data/2014/09/11/pods/10057-0-2965978-0-scan.pdf</URL>
    <DateSigned>Not signed</DateSigned>
 </item>
</Pods>
```

I would like to get the conents of the `<URL>` where `<DateSigned>` is not equal to "Not Signed"

I have tried

```
Dim URLNode As XmlNodeList = doc.SelectNodes("//ITEM[DateSigned=Not Signed]/URL")
```

but this says invalid token I am unsure what I have dine wrong.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to simply wrap `Not signed` within single-quotes to make it recognized as string value. Also, XML is case-sensitive, use the correct cases :

```
Dim URLNode As XmlNodeList = _
                doc.SelectNodes("//item[DateSigned='Not signed']/URL")
```

or if you really meant to get `<item>` where `<DateSigned>` **is not** equals `Not signed` :

```
Dim URLNode As XmlNodeList = _
                doc.SelectNodes("//item[DateSigned != 'Not signed']/URL")
```